# cmake and include directories across projects

Tags: gcc, cmake

I'm trying to split a large cmake-managed project into a collection of smaller projects. I'm having trouble making cmake accept propagation of include directories. I'm currently using the cmake version that comes with ubuntu 14.04 (2.8). I can switch to 3.x if it really is necessary, but I'd rather not if I can help it.

Consider an example where a certain directory of my source tree consists of a separable, isolate-able library. It has no other dependencies within my source tree, and has so far been managed by a combination of

```
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(smdir)
```

and within smdir:

```
ADD_LIBRARY(something STATIC something.c something.h)
```

In other areas where `something` is used as a dependency, the following works perfectly:

```
ADD_LIBRARY(something_else STATIC ...)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(something_else something)
```

All of this happening inside cmake macros / functions that do some other name mangling, so please forgive me if the precise code listed here is slightly incorrect.

What I'm now trying to do is pull `something` completely out of my source tree. I should note that these are embedded libraries for use on bare metal microcontrollers, and it's not something I'm installing on the build machine.

The basic compile scripts for `something` work pretty much as expected with minimal changes. My approach to integrate this (now externally compiled and managed) library with the rest of the codebase is by exporting the compiled library from the build tree, and importing it into my other project. This approach is based largely on the `Exporting from a Build Tree` section of https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/Exporting_and_Importing_Targets. I have tried to do this in the following way :

```
TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(something PUBLIC /path/to/smdir/src)
EXPORT(TARGETS something FILE something-config.cmake)
INSTALL(FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/something-config.cmake 
            DESTINATION ${PLATFORM_PACKAGES_PATH})
```

where ${PLATFORM_PACKAGES_PATH} is some system folder where I intend to collect all of these config files. The generated config file looks reasonable, and is installed to the correct place just fine, and has the following lines (among many others):

```
add_library(something STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(something PROPERTIES
  INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "/path/to/smdir/src"
)
set_property(TARGET something APPEND PROPERTY IMPORTED_CONFIGURATIONS RELWITHDEBINFO)
set_target_properties(something PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LINK_INTERFACE_LANGUAGES_RELWITHDEBINFO "C" IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELWITHDEBINFO "/correct/path/to/something.a")
```

The problem comes when importing this library, which I do using:

```
ADD_LIBRARY(something STATIC IMPORTED)
SET_PROPERTY(TARGET something PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION "${PLATFORM_PACKAGES_PATH}") 
GET_PROPERTY(public_include_dirs TARGET something PROPERTY INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
```

The build of any library which lists something as a dependency does not include the INCLUDE_FOLDERS for something in the gcc command. The `public_include_dirs` variable which I try to read here with GET_PROPERTY is blank.

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated, including suggestions for a 'cleaner' or better approach.

Comment: You incorrectly interpret `Exporting from a Build Tree` section of the reffered tutorial: lines `add_library(IMPORTED)` and `SET_PROPERTY(TARGET .. IMPORTED_LOCATION)` *are contained* in the `.cmake` file which you have exported before. You need to include this file for get its effect: `include("${PLATFORM_PACKAGES_PATH}/something-config.cmake")`. Note also, that exported build tree is normally [not installed](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/export.html): `The file created by this command is specific to the build tree and should never be installed.`

Comment: @Tsyvarev Ah. That makes things make a little more sense, though with the following two caveats : (a) Given that the paths in *config.cmake are hardcoded and absolute, what would be the problem in installing it outside the build tree? (b) if not importing the file and using it as listed in the question, cmake still dies if it can't actually find the *config.cmake. I took this to mean that cmake is actually using the file at some point.

Comment: `what would be the problem in installing it outside the build tree?` - Exporting loses many properties of the original build tree. This is why exported tree is not intended for install. `I took this to mean that cmake is actually using the file at some point.` - at `include()` point CMake just interprets all commands in the included file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you extracted the module entirely, effectively you've created a 3rd party lib from the perspective of your importing project.

So if you are already exporting `cmake` package/config scripts, why not import them normally with `find_package()`. Pass `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` to equal wherever you installed your extracted library originally with `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`.

So to sum up:

1. Pass `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/path/to/target/prefix` when invoking cmake on your extracted library. `make && make install` it.
2. Restructure your cmake logic inside your importing project using `find_package()`.
3. Use the library as per normal with `target_link_libraries()` to pick up a ref to your extracted library.
4. Pass `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/path/to/target/prefix` when invoking cmake on your importing project. Then `make` it.

Comment: There's no inherent usefulness to installing the library on the build machine (cross compiled for some other platform). Using the build tree itself seemed appealing - and possibly easier. The posted code is a minimal sample. I'm actually rebuilding the lib for multiple platforms (and mangling names to reflect the target platform). So far I've restricted the install to just copying the config.cmake into a folder. I suppose I could create an artificial INSTALL_PREFIX to create an 'installation' which cmake can readily recognize, it just seemed unnatural to me. I shall give it a go, though.

Comment: Then why not create, say, a `dist` subdirectory in your local build tree for it and pass a `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` that points to that `dist` directory?

Comment: I ended up changing my ${PLATFORM_PACKAGES_PATH} into a full install prefix instead of using it just as a container for the config files. It took some effort to get it just right for find_packages, but it's finally compiling now - modulo some issues with passing along the header deps up the chain.